# Remove params from JSON in SQL Server

Tags: json, sql-server

There is a JSON column in SQL Server tables with data like:

```
["1","2","3","4"]
```

and I want to delete "3" or ("2","4") (for example) from it.

Can I do it with `Json_Modify` or anything else?

Comment: You can parse the JSON and then filter it using WHERE Clause ,

DECLARE @JSON VARCHAR(2000)='["1","2","3","4"]' 

SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@JSON)
WHERE Value NOT IN (1,2)

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: @Zhorov hi, it is 2019

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON modify can modify by `PATH` if you have not any key to modify and just a simple list like that you can do this:

```
DECLARE @JsonList NVARCHAR(1000) = N'["1","2","3","4"]';
DECLARE @NewList NVARCHAR(1000);

SET @NewList =
(
    SELECT CONCAT('[', STRING_AGG(CONCAT('"', oj.Value, '"'), ','), ']')
    FROM OPENJSON(@JsonList) AS oj
    WHERE oj.Value NOT IN ( 2, 4 )
);

PRINT @NewList
```